# Open CTI not working for managed package

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, opencti

I am facing this issue, on an unmanaged package my Open CTI methods(Enable click to dial and screen pop) seem to work fine, but on a managed package it doesn't work.

Enable click to dial method:

```
var enableClickToDialcallback = function(response) 
{
     if (response.success) 
     {
        console.log('API method call executed successfully! returnValue:', response.returnValue);
     } 
     else 
     {
        console.log( 'Click to dial unsuccessful ' + response.errors);
         
     } 
  };

  function enableClickToDial() {
      sforce.opencti.enableClickToDial({callback: enableClickToDialcallback});
  }
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you highlight any code which you think might be causing issue, or maybe share code part which is working in unmanaged package and you are expecting it to work in managed package as well.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 added the code in post for Enable Click to dial method.

Comment: So you must be getting error in the `errorThrown` what is that?

Comment: No errors, that's the issue.

Comment: Anything we see in the console tab or network tab?

Comment: In enableClickToDial() I added a console.log statement **before invoking enableCllickToDial** only that is visible. After that nothing related to open cti, no errors etc.

Comment: Not sure what to say then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed the issue was with my registered namespace. It contained underscore "_" in it. When I created a namespace in another org (both subscriber org and where I developed my package) with just camel case notation it worked fine. My open CTI methods started executing callbacks.